# Implementing Remote Api Shell (Python) in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, client

Actually what I'm trying to implement is that, I have to access appengine datastore remotely using **remote_api_shell.py**. But the problem I'm facing is I'm able to logging in but couldn't access the entitys modules in my app. the steps for the procedure is not clear anywhere so I'm not able to proceed further.

I referred the articles

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi  and

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

They have used a command like

*python $GAE_SDK_ROOT/remote_api_shell.py -s your_app_id.appspot.com*

I dont know where to type it. I used command prompt for which i modified the above as

*c:\program files(x86)\google\google_appengine\python remote_api_shell.py -s your_app_id.appspot.com*

Its logging in. I'm able to save some entities in my datastore but unable to access my modules. i think there is a some kind of directories i want to specify or there are steps i have to follow before this which I might have missed. So i looking forward for Some Help to achieve it successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to access my modules"? How are you saving entities if you can't import your code? Exactly what code are you trying, and what error do you get?

Comment: i use a module named main.py. if I try "import main", it said no modules named main. Since db modules are imported by default I can use them to create entities and save them to the datastore. Bt that are not useful to me, Since the main module is the one i needed to create entities of my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off `cd` to your application directory.

The run the remote shell as per the docs

python $GAE_SDK_ROOT/remote_api_shell.py -s your_app_id.appspot.com

If you use appengine_config.py to set up all your paths manually import that into the shell.
Other wise you should be able to import any modules etc  that are defined at the root level of  your application directory.

Comment: THANKS. I spent too much time to figure out why it was not importing my `models` file, i forgot to `cd` in the application directory before run the remote!.